# Bootstrap HTML Mysql form with file not uploading

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I made a form with an attachment in it. The attachment name information is successfully saved in mysql but why is it not saved in the destination file?

here's the script for attachment form

```html
<form class="forms-sample formOnce" method="post" action="cdd_format.php" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">


  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_uid">Format Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_uid">Title*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_uid">Content*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea style="height:100px;" class="form-control tinyMce" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_uid">Attachment</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class='form-group col-md-12'>
            <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" accept="application/pdf" class="file-upload-default" multiple>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control file-upload-info" id="file-upload-info" disabled placeholder="Upload File PDF">
              <span class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded" id="file-upload-browse" type="button">Browse</button>
                        </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_uid"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="hidden" name="format_edit">
          <hr style="border: 1px solid #9900ff;">
          <button type="submit" id="format_edit" name="format_edit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btnSubmit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</form>
```

and here script input data to mysql

```
 $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);

    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);

    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $id = strip_tags($_POST['id']);


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {

    $targetfolder   = "../cddhr/MCU/";
    $nm_file        = $id;
    $temp           = explode(".", $_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
    $newfilename    = "file-" . $nm_file . '.' . end($temp);
    $foto           = $targetfolder . $newfilename;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $foto);



    $attachment   = $newfilename;


    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("update cdd_format set attachment=:attachment where id=:id ");

    $stmt2->bindParam(':id', $id);

    $stmt2->bindParam(':attachment', $attachment);

    $stmt2->execute();

}


    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("update cdd_format set name=:name, content=:content, title=:title where id=:id ");

    $stmt2->bindParam(':id', $id);

    $stmt2->bindParam(':name', $name);

    $stmt2->bindParam(':content', $content);

    $stmt2->bindParam(':title', $title);



    $stmt2->execute();
```

there is no error message on the system. and the file folder actually exists. How do I get files to be stored in that folder? please help and thank you

Comment: check your path first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working in my system. Got the file into the desired directory. You can do the following task.

1. Check if the uploads dir is writeable
2. Grant permissions to that upload directory
3. try copy function instead of move_uploaded_file

Comment: thank you, the problem is actually simple. I haven't given permission to put the file into the folder because I use FTP to save file